# In Swift how to create Custom Alert View

Tags: ios, swift, uialertview

I have to implement a Custom alerts in my App programmatically using Swift language. i tried implementing using some third party library  "SCLAlertView" but not able to understand from that, i need a implement  simple alert pop ups with dynamic message and number of button changes in App. As there were lots of AlertView in my App. so i  need to update the dynamically.

below i have attached an sample image of custom alert how it looks to implement

[image]

[image]

Please help me to implement this feature.

Comment: What's custom about your alert? Why can't you use a normal `UIAlertController`? (`UIAlertView` is deprecated).

Answer (score 2):

After the installing pod with `pod SCLAlertView`

You can choose `Alert view Style` and `Alert View Animation` style with these enums

```
 enum SCLAlertViewStyle: Int {
        case Success, Error, Notice, Warning, Info, Edit, Wait
    }

    public enum SCLAnimationStyle {
      case NoAnimation, TopToBottom, BottomToTop, LeftToRight, RightToLeft
    }
```

SCLAlertView has many Control groups like add textField , buttons and icons

here is a adding button function codes

```
let alertView = SCLAlertView()
alertView.addButton("First Button", target:self, selector:Selector("firstButton"))
alertView.addButton("Second Button") {
    println("Second button tapped")
}
alertView.showSuccess("Button View", subTitle: "This alert view has buttons")
```

and Alert view custom types

```
SCLAlertView().showError("Hello Error", subTitle: "This is a more descriptive error text.") // Error
SCLAlertView().showNotice("Hello Notice", subTitle: "This is a more descriptive notice text.") // Notice
SCLAlertView().showWarning("Hello Warning", subTitle: "This is a more descriptive warning text.") // Warning
SCLAlertView().showInfo("Hello Info", subTitle: "This is a more descriptive info text.") // Info
SCLAlertView().showEdit("Hello Edit", subTitle: "This is a more descriptive info text.") // Edit
```

in Github Page you will find many beatiful desing alert views , it is easy to use

https://github.com/vikmeup/SCLAlertView-Swift

Answer (score 1):

Just add different UIAlertAction to your UIAlertController whenever you want it to.

```
let alertAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "YES", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: {
    //Code goes here
})

let alertAction2: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "NO", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: {
   //Code goes here
})

let alertAction3: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Maybe", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: {
   //Code goes here
})

alert.addAction(alertAction)
alert.addAction(alertAction2)
alert.addAction(alertAction3)
```

You can dynamically add UIAlertAction's to your UIAlertController depending on your needs. If you only need two buttons, then don't add `alertAction3`. If you need three or four, then add them as necessary.